# How to place a tikz picture inside a proof environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, align

I am having trouble to place a tikz-picture inside a proof environment just beside the text and the align environment. I tried to use "wrapfigure", but my picture is always placed at the bottom. Below you can find the smallest example I was able to generate.

Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[style=numeric,firstinits,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % The Font Type
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xspace}




\bibliography{library.bib}  




\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}



\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}{Definition}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily}{th}  
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lemma}{Lemma}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily}{th}  
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{corollary}{Corollary}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily}{th}



\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}
\newtheorem{reminder}{Reminder}


% General Math Commands
\newcommand{\conjugate}[1]{\overline{#1}}







\begin{document}

\smallskip
    \begin{theorem}{}{}
        Some text
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{proof}
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAA
            
            
                \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \scalebox{0.8}{
                        \draw (1.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,0);
                        \draw (2.25,0) -- (2.25,1.5);
                        \draw (1.5,0.75) -- (3,0.75);
                        \filldraw[red] (2.5,0.4) circle (2pt) node [below] {$A$};
                        \draw[red]  (2.5,0.4) -- (3,0);
                                
                        \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (1.5,0) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (3,0) circle (2pt) node [below right] {$A$};
                        \filldraw[black] (4.5,0) circle (2pt);
                
                        \filldraw[black] (0,1.5) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (1.5,1.5) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (3,1.5) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (4.5,1.5) circle (2pt);
                
                        \filldraw[black] (0,-1.5) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (1.5,-1.5) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (3,-1.5) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (4.5,-1.5) circle (2pt);
                
                        \filldraw[black] (0,3) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (1.5,3) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (3,3) circle (2pt);
                        \filldraw[black] (4.5,3) circle (2pt);
                        }   
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{wrapfigure}
                
            \begin{align*}
                N(\rho) &= N \biggl( \alpha - \beta \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \biggr) 
                        = N\biggl(\beta \cdot \biggl(\frac{\alpha}{\beta} - \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\biggr)\biggr) \\
                        &= N(\beta) \cdot N\biggl(\frac{\alpha}{\beta} -\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\biggr)\biggr)
                        \le \frac{1}{2} N(\beta) < N(\beta)
            \end{align*}
    \end{proof}
    
    
\end{document}
```